# Where can I found the documentation of the test() method in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-testing-library

I am learning to use the Testing Library for React Apps but I can't find any documentation regarding the "test()" method, which I presume is a method coming from a global object somewhere.

Example:

```
test("renders Hello World as a text", () => {});
```

Comment: That totally depends upon which testing library are you using in your React project?

Comment: `test` is not a testing-library method. It's part of Jest (assuming you're using create-react-app) https://jestjs.io/docs/api#testname-fn-timeout

Comment: Sure, Jest is a dependency already built-in with create React app in my project. The question is: I am noy importing test ('import {test} from "@testing-library/jest-dom"') so how is it working at all?

Comment: `test` doesn't come from `@testing-library/jest-dom`. Jest is taking the test files and runs them with the `test` function in its scope.

Comment: So when I run "react-scripts test"/"npm test" (is a script) Jest is being activate built-in and finding any test() function to do the tests?

Comment: Yes. Jest is a "test-runner". create-react-app uses jest https://create-react-app.dev/docs/running-tests